# Close firefox tab with Javascript

Tags: firefox, tabs

**(Disclaimer)** I have read threads that this can't be done, and this can be done so i'm kind of confuse weather it can or not. These threads were also somewhat old so i'm asking again to see if the answer has been found by a different audience. If i annoy someone by asking this question again, i truly apologize. This was never my intention.

I have a website that sends you an email to confirm your information. When you click the link in the email, a new tab opens with a form that has your information filled out and some check boxes to agree or disagree to the terms. Once you check all the requirements, there is a button at the bottom that says agree. Right now if you click it, it submits the page, resets the fields you clicked on and i think this is a bit confusing to the end user.

I was wanting to close the page for them once they click the agree button. so now i have a jQuery dialog box pop up asking if they want to stay or leave the page. if they click leave the page, it will close that tab for them. This works in IE(surprisingly), Chrome, Safari, and Opera. Firefox is another story.

Can someone please help me or tell me if this can be done in Firefox?
This was my referance. http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html

And here is the code i have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("##agree").dialog({ 
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height:230,
    width:400,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      "Leave this page": function() {
        $("##VerificationForm").submit();//nothing to do with closing tab
        open(location, '_parent','').close();
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      },
      Cancel: function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    } 
  });

  $("##agreebtn").click(
    function checkAndSubmit(action) {
      if(validateForm()&&validateAgreement(action)) {//nothing to do with closing tab
        $("##agree").dialog('open');
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads stating that it can be done were right at one point, but they aren't now. FireFox has patched that exploit out. 
You cannot close a tab or window in FireFox that your script didn't open in the first place.

You can go into your FireFox:config and change the values around to your liking, but for security reasons, it's defaulted to "false".